# Unable to run a Java code in IntelliJ (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am currently a beginner in Java especially in Spring Boot and I am trying to execute a Java code in IntelliJ. However, the run button is not enabled. May I know the possible cause of this problem?

[image]

The run button is enabled.

Comment: Try hitting the gradle refresh button on the top right of your editor tab

Comment: I tried to click the gradle refresh button on the top right but the run button is still not enabled.

Comment: The presence of the `mvnw` files suggests that this is using a Maven build and not a Gradle build. IDEA supports both, but you might have imported the project wrong and/or might need to enable the Maven tool window.

Comment: Have you set up java sdk?

Answer (score -1):

- The bell with the red dot indicates some error.
- The refresh button top right in the editor indicates that Maven need dependency refresh.
- And after right click / run on the DemoApplication it should appear in the run configuration list.